# how do I nest a javascript object inside another one?

Tags: javascript

I receive an error of 'mydoc.docMeta is undefined' when I try to do this:

```
var mydoc = {};
mydoc.docMeta.keyword = "somevalue";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `mydoc.docMeta` is also an object, you have to define it first:

```
var mydoc = {};
mydoc.docMeta = {};
mydoc.docMeta.keyword = "somevalue";
```

Or just use a literal:

```
var mydoc = {
    docMeta : {
        keyword : "somevalue"
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to nest one more level:

```
var mydoc = {
   docMeta: {
       keyword: "somevalue"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want `docMeta` to be another object literal?

```
var mydoc = { docMeta: {} };
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var mydoc = {};
mydoc.docMeta = {
    keyword : "somevalue"
};
```

You are declaring mydoc as an object, but then you are trying to set an attribute of an attribute of an object, first you have to declare that attribute as an object as well